# Use lambda or helper method in python to avoid for loop duplication

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following simple class and am wondering if there is a simple way to use a `lambda`, `decorator`, or `helper method`, etc... to avoid the duplicated *for loop* that appears in each method in `CODENAMES` and `ALL_DEFAULTS`?

```
class classproperty(object):
    """
    When used to decorate a method in a class, that method will behave
    like as a class property.
    """
    def __init__(self, f):
        # f - the func that's being decorated
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        # call the func on the class
        return self.f(cls)

class PermissionInfo(object):

    MODELS = ['ticket', 'person', 'role']
    PERMS = ['view', 'add', 'change', 'delete']

    @classproperty
    def CODENAMES(cls):
        codenames = []
        for p in cls.PERMS:
            for m in cls.MODELS:
                codenames.append('{}_{}'.format(p, m))
        return codenames

    @classproperty
    def ALL_DEFAULTS(cls):
        ret = {}

        for p in cls.PERMS:
            for m in cls.MODELS:
                ret["{}_{}".format(p, m)] = False

        return ret
```

Duplicated for loop is this section of each method:

```
# ...
for p in cls.PERMS:
    for m in cls.MODELS:
#...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) within helper method to generate the names:

```
from itertools import product

def names(cls):
    yield from ('_'.join(x) for x in product(cls.PERMS, cls.MODELS))
```

Then you could change your class to utilize it:

```
@classproperty
def CODENAMES(cls):
    return list(names(cls))

@classproperty
def ALL_DEFAULTS(cls):
    return dict.fromkeys(names(cls), False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use something like:

```
MODEL_PERMS = list(map(lambda t: "{}_{}".format(t[0],t[1]), itertools.product(MODELS, PERMS)))
```

Comment: Meh. @niemmi's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product


class PermissionInfo(object):

    MODELS = ['ticket', 'person', 'role']
    PERMS = ['view', 'add', 'change', 'delete']
    PRODUCT = product(PERMS, MODELS)
    CODENAMES = ['{}_{}'.format(p, m) for (p, m) in PRODUCT]
    ALL_DEFAULTS = {codename: False for codename in CODENAMES}
```

ohhh shiny :-}

Comment: Note that this is different from the original code since `ALL_DEFAULTS` can be easily mutated. Assume you generate custom permissions like this: `perm = PermissionInfo.ALL_DEFAULTS; perm['view_ticket'] = True`. With original implementation this is not an issue but with your implementation defaults will change.